# Azure app Service not picking up Gitlab Container Registry Configuration as Private Repository

Tags: azure, docker, gitlab

I have an application container pushed to a gitlab container registry. I am trying to deploy it into azure web app service as a container. I did the configuration as best as I could understand based on the documentation from azure. But I don't understand what I am missing because azure logs show azure still trying to connect to docker hub registry.

[image: Here consider that image with tag latest is provided i.e image:latest]

In the logs I get the following

```
2019-05-13 09:21:49.741 ERROR - DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status code=InternalServerError, response={"message":"Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/<image-name>/manifests/latest: unauthorized: incorrect username or password"}

2019-05-13 09:21:49.743 ERROR - Pulling docker image <image-name> failed:
2019-05-13 09:21:49.743 INFO  - Pulling image from Docker hub: library/<image-name>
2019-05-13 09:21:50.795 ERROR - DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status code=NotFound, response={"message":"pull access denied for <image-name>, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'"}

2019-05-13 09:21:50.797 ERROR - Image pull failed: Verify docker image configuration and credentials (if using private repository)
```

Can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong here? I believe the problem is the registry url config. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can try if you can use the username and password to pull the image locally.

Comment: found the solution, I was giving only the image name had to put the full name of the image registry registry.gitlab.com/<group name>/<image name>

Comment: You can just delete the problem or add the answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For anyone else who faces the same problem, my problem was that I was giving only the image name, had to put the full name of the image registry `registry.gitlab.com/<group name>/<image name>`

Answer (score 3):

Since it took me a while to fiddle that together, this is what helped me most. (Thanks [@Hassaan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2229210/hassaan) for your answer that pointed me in the right direction)

**GitLab**

You need to be aware of your container registry located in GitLab.
Check [image naming conventions](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/container_registry/#image-naming-convention) for that.

If you are using GitLab Cloud registry URL is: https://registry.gitlab.com

Once you logged into GitLab check your project and navigate to "Packages & Registries" and click on "Container Registry".

If you already published an image, it will be shown there in the list. What you see there is what I will call "full-image-name".

It'll be most likely <namespace>/<project>/<image-name>.
We need that full-image-name later. Click on that image in that list to get a list of image tags. You will have to selecte a tag to use for later.

If you did not publish an image to that registry yet, check the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/container_registry/) to get started.

**Azure Web App**

Navigate to your App Service and find "Container settings (Classic)" in the left side menu.

Then simply fill in required data.

- Server URL: https://registry.gitlab.com
- Full Image Name and Tag: <full-image-name>:<tag> (see above)

If you are not sure what to put into login and password have a look at how to [authenticate with the container registry](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/container_registry/#authenticate-with-the-container-registry).